# Is there a way to convert BinaryFile(.wav) into file-like object in Python3 - Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Python 3.6.9
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.16.0

on an POST call, I am sending a .wav file from postman. I am receiving that file on Flask by using the below lines

```
length = request.headers["Content-Length"]
Binaryfile = request.get_data(length)
```

My Binaryfile will look like this
RIFFzuWAVEfmt >}dataVu ???someRandomData

Now, I need to read this data through python and need to send it into

```
import speech_recognition as sr
audioFile = sr.AudioFile(here, need a file-like object created from binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
import io

Binaryfile = request.get_data(length)
file = io.BytesIO(Binaryfile)
audioFile = sr.audioFile(file)
```

Comment: --SOLVED--
@Marco Bonelli, Thank you for your response. I tried passing file directly into sr.audioFile(), but I am facing the below error
"Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format"

hence, I have created a .wav file in my local folder from file.read() method, and passed it's path into
audioFile = sr.audioFile(audio file path)

it works :)
Thank you